# How to use reverse proxy on apache for a specific url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I have a load balancer that balances 2 servers A & B on the cloud both of which have apache running on them. A & B can serve all the requests except search which is powered only by A. The search request is through `http://example.com/search`. If B was to receive such a request, how can I forward this request to A and the serve the response received from server A to client?

PS: I am running Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache's [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#ProxyPass) directive seems to do what you're asking for.

You could do something like this in server B configuration:

`ProxyPass /search http://server-A.example.com`